# Cannot access object from GraphQL query (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, import, module, graphql, graphql-js

Subgraph query returns results to console, but my javascript module can't access any values from it, returning an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'symbol')
```

According to everything I read online, this is how to access object properties.

quni.mjs:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export async function quni() {
  const uniData = async () => {
    var result;
    try{
      result = await axios.post(
        'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/ianlapham/uniswap-v3-polygon',
        {   
          query:`
          {
            pools(
              first: 2,
            where: {
              liquidity_gt: 100
            }
          )
            {
              id
              token1{symbol}
              token0{symbol}
            }
          } 
          `
        }    
      );
    } catch(error){
      console.error(error);
    }
    const unipairs = result.data.data.pools;
    //console.log(unipairs);
    return result.data.data.pools;
  }
  return uniData();
}
quni();
```

quniparse.mjs:

```
    import { quni } from './quni.mjs';
    async function unicheck() {
    var uni = await quni();
    var unitoken0 = uni.token0.symbol;
    var unitoken1 = uni.token1.symbol;
    var ticker = toString([unitoken0+"/"+unitoken1]);
    console.log(ticker)
    };
    unicheck();
```

Solutions I've tried:

`JSON.stringify(unipairs)` to try accessing using JSON objects in quniparse.mjs, but that yields identical results.

`fs.writeFile('./unipairs', JSON.stringify(unipairs), null, 2)` to see if accessing properties from .json file might help.

All yield identical results (cannot read 'symbol').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed a loop, ex.;

```
uni.forEach(unipair => {
    console.log(unipair);
```